# How to display multiple row in a single row which as same description_id in another table in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
description_id       description
--------------      -------------
1                   Ampicillin Oral
1                   Ofloxacin Oral
1                   Sulfamoxole+Trimethoprim Oral
2                   Letrozole Oral
2                   Flunarizine Oral
```

description_id  from table1 and description from table2.

and result should be

```
description_id       description
--------------       -----------
1                    Ampicillin Oral,Ofloxacin Oral, Sulfamoxole+Trimethoprim Oral
2                    Letrozole Oral, Flunarizine Oral
```

Comment: Will it always be two items or less that it matches up to?  Or is there a many clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `table2` also has a `description_id` column, and that it is the primary key in dbo.table1:

```
SELECT description_id, STUFF((SELECT N',' + description
  FROM dbo.table2 WHERE description_id = t1.description_id
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'')
FROM dbo.table1 AS t1;
```

In SQL Server 2017 or greater, this is a lot tidier:

```
SELECT t1.description_id, STRING_AGG(t2.description, N',')
  FROM dbo.table1 AS t1
  INNER JOIN dbo.table2 AS t2
  ON t1.description_id = t2.description_id
  GROUP BY t1.description_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a an aggregate function that can concatenate the description strings together.

However, although SQL Server has built in functions for aggregating numbers (e.g. SUM and AVERAGE), there is no built-in aggregate string concatenation function.

This leaves you with a two main options:

1. Perform the concatenation on the client.
2. Use a workaround technique such as XML PATH, a recursive CTE, or using an embedded Common Language Runtime package.

For option 2, there are some articles on how to do this around, e.g. [this article about concatenating row values](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/). And indeed - I've just seen Aaron Bertrand's answer come in, which 
shows you exactly how to do it in your situation :)